# Number of CPUs per Task in Spark

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark

I don't quite understand `spark.task.cpus` parameter. It seems to me that a “task” corresponds to a “thread” or a "process", if you will, within the executor. Suppose that I set "spark.task.cpus" to 2.

1. How can a thread utilize two CPUs simultaneously? Couldn't it require locks and cause synchronization problems?
2. I'm looking at `launchTask()` function in deploy/executor/Executor.scala, and I don't see any notion of "number of cpus per task" here. So where/how does Spark eventually allocate more than one cpu to a task in the standalone mode?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge `spark.task.cpus` controls the parallelism of tasks in you cluster in the case where some particular tasks are known to have their own internal (custom) parallelism.

**In more detail:**
We know that `spark.cores.max` defines how many threads (aka cores) your application needs. If you leave `spark.task.cpus = 1` then you will have #spark.cores.max number of concurrent Spark tasks running at the same time.

You will only want to change `spark.task.cpus` if you know that your tasks are themselves parallelized (maybe each of your task spawns two threads, interacts with external tools, etc.) By setting `spark.task.cpus` accordingly, you become a good "citizen". Now if you have spark.cores.max=10 and spark.task.cpus=2 Spark will only create 10/2=5 concurrent tasks. Given that your tasks need (say) 2 threads internally the total number of executing threads will never be more than 10. This means that you never go above your initial contract (defined by `spark.cores.max`).

Comment: I would add that it is used all over the source as `CPUS_PER_TASK` although it is not really enforced on runtime (more resource utilization hint than a hard limitation)

Comment: do you have any example showing how a task could internally be parallelized? 

@zero323, CPUS_PER_TASK is used in a very high level scheduling stuff, it is never being passed to the executor. So, my question is "how do we make sure that a task gets spark.task.cpus cores that it requested?"

Comment: The simplest  way (not very useful): `rdd.mapPartitions(_.toVector.par.map(foo))`. And to answer your second question - we simply don't. It only says that if you declare four executor cores, and `spark.task.cpus` equal 2 then it can start only 2 tasks. But there is physical cores allocation or similar stuff. `core` in Spark is just a thread.

Comment: @marios How to set this property spark.task.cpus ? Can I set in spark-submit command?

Comment: @Kishore you can pass that via a --conf parameter in spark-submit,

Comment: If I understand this correctly a single task on an executor can use any number of threads in parallell, that is not something spark decides? Let's say I run the sql.functions.from_json function on a column in a dataframe. Could that function then use all available cores to deserialize the dataframe even though it takes place in a single task on the executors?

Answer (score -1):

if I have set spark.task.cpus to 4 and spark.executor.cores to 4 -- this would mean I am spinning up one task per executor. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34573285)