# Is a single Spark task ever multithreaded?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I'm trying to figure out if a single task is ever run using all available cores on the executor? Ie, if a stage contains only one task, does that mean the task is a single threaded single core processing on the executor or could the task use all available cores in a multithreaded fashion "under the covers"?

I'm running ETL jobs in Azure Databricks on one worker (hence one executor) and at one point in the pipeline a single job creates a single stage that runs a single task to process the entire dataset. The task takes a few minutes to complete.

I want to understand if a single task can use all available executor cores running functions in parallell or not? In this case I deserialize json messages with the from_json function and save them as parquet files. I'm worried this is a single threaded process going on in the single task.

```
spark
    .read
    .table("input")
    .withColumn("Payload", from_json($"Payload", schema))
    .write
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .saveAsTable("output")
```

Comment: possible dup of [Number of CPUs per Task in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36671832/647053) see the accepted answer.

Comment: I saw that answer. As I understand it spark.task.cpu and spark.cores.max actually just limits the amount tasks created on the driver side, it does not decide the behaviour of a task on the executor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking the `Spark UI` and see only one task, this is definitely single cored and single threaded.

For instance, if you do a join and then a trasnformation, you will see anything like `200` tasks by default. Which means `200` "thread" are computing in parallel.

If you want to check the number of executors, you can click on the `stages` tab, click on any stage and you will see how many executors were used.

Comment: Thanks, I only have one executor with 8 cores. If there's only a single task in a stage I can be sure a single core is doing all the work. It's weird, the task input size is 5,7 GB, I can't understand how all that data ended up in a single partition. Have to try to repartition the dataset before I run this part of the pipeline.

Comment: @Molotch Exactly ! The partitionning is usually a solution to explore

Comment: They may not all be computing parallel unless you have 200 executors at your disposal, that was my understanding.

Comment: @BlueSheepToken I think I found the problem too, coalesce(1) might be pushed up for some reason I haven't understood yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494656/how-to-prevent-spark-optimization

Comment: @Molotch Thanks for getting me informed !
I do not know about this particular optimization, but yeah, Spark does some pushdown predicates optimizations. If you have the plans I might dig a little bit more :)