# How many concurrent tasks in one executor and how Spark handles multithreading among tasks in one executor?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-spark, concurrency, hadoop-yarn

In Spark, how many tasks are executed in parallel at a time? Discussions are found in
[How are stages split into tasks in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528047/how-are-stages-split-into-tasks-in-spark) and
[How DAG works under the covers in RDD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836316/how-dag-works-under-the-covers-in-rdd)

But I do not find clear conclusion there.

Consider the following scenarios (assume `spark.task.cpus = 1`, and ignore `vcore` concept for simplicity):

- 10 executors (2 cores/executor), 10 partitions => I think the number of concurrent tasks at a time is **10**
- 10 executors (2 cores/executor), 2 partitions  => I think the number of concurrent tasks at a time is **2**
- 10 executors (2 cores/executor), 20 partitions  => I think the number of concurrent tasks at a time is **20**
- 10 executors (**1** cores/executor), 20 partitions  => I think the number of concurrent tasks at a time is **10**

Am I correct? Regarding the 3rd case, will it be **20** considering multi-threading (i.e. 2 threads because there are 2 cores) inside one executor?

---

**UPDATE1**

If the 3rd case is correct, it means:

- when idle cores inside an executor are available, Spark could automatically decide to trigger multithreads in that executor
- when there is only one core in the executor, multithread won't happen in that executor.

If this is true, isn't the behavior of Spark in an executor a bit **uncertain** (single thread v.s. multithread)?

Note that the code that is shipped from driver to the executors may not have considered automicity problem using e.g. **synchronized** keyword.

How is this handled by Spark?

Comment: You are correct (including 3rd case). One other factor to consider is vcores.

On Hortonworks/ Cloudera, there is an option for admin to split a single physical core into set virtual cores.

Each virtual core would be able to execute a task on a partition.

Comment: Correct for most common cases. There is however a `spark.task.cpus` setting which can alter that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671832/number-of-cpus-per-task-in-spark

Comment: @mazaneicha Thanks for the comment. But I think `spark.task.cpus` is about nb. of cpus **per task**, while my question is about nb. of tasks, which is different, but your link is also interesting to know. :)

Comment: If you assign 2 cpus per task, then an executor with 4 cores will only be able to run 2 tasks concurrently, whereas normally it would run 4.

Comment: @mazaneicha Makes sense, i will put the assumption `spark.task.cpus = 1` in the question. But here you're talking about multithreading inside one task (1 task has 2 threads), and the question is more about multithreading among tasks (1 task has 1 thread, but 2 tasks running concurrently in one executor)

Comment: A nice [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfiJQ7wg81Y&ab_channel=SparkSummit) related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all the 4 cases are correct, and the 4th case makes sense in reality ("overbook" cores). We should normally consider a factor of 2 to 4 for the nb. of partitions, i.e. nb. of partitions equals to 2 to 4 times of nb. of total cpu cores in the cluster.

Regarding threading, 2 tasks in one executor running concurrently should not have issues regarding multi-threading, as each task is handling its own set of `RDD`.

If `spark.task.cpus = 2` is set, which means 2 cpu cores per task, then IMO there might be race condition problem (if there're `var`), but usually we are handling immutable values like `RDD`, so there should merely have issues either.

Answer (score 1):

I think  you are right, this depend on your executor number and the cores, one partition create a task running on one core .

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean, if the nb. of partitions is larger than the nb. of nodes (assume 1 core per node), it normally doesn't make sense? Consider the 4th case..